# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod . changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/Firestore` inside your development pod

Tags: ios, flutter, cocoapods

I am facing the below error after upgrading flutter and to the latest flutter packages.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Firestore":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/Firestore (= 8.15.0)

  In Podfile:
    cloud_firestore (from `.symlinks/plugins/cloud_firestore/ios`) was resolved to 3.4.5, which depends on
      Firebase/Firestore (= 9.4.0)


You have either:
 * changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/Firestore` inside your development pod `cloud_firestore`.
   You should run `pod update Firebase/Firestore` to apply changes you've made.

[!] Automatically assigning platform `iOS` with version `12.0` on target `Runner` because no platform was specified. Please specify a platform for this target in your Podfile. See `https://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podfile.html#platform`.
```

[image: Pod file error]

Answer (score 8):

I faced this issue and solve it

- delete pod.lock file in ios directory
- run `pod repo update` command in terminal
- run `pod install`

I hope it works!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but not with Firebase. the error was for AgoraIrisRTC_iOS. After deleting PodFile.lock and "pod install" in iOS directory the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

After deleting the /ios/pods.lock file in the project, it started downloading the pods for the latest version.